# Посоветуйте модуль на Python для разработки android \ ios приложений

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, мобильная-разработка, модули

Посоветуйте модуль на *Python* для разработки **android \ ios** приложений. Можно только **android**, спасибо

Comment: Если забанили на гугле, держи https://tproger.ru/translations/python-development-on-android/

Comment: Для андроид можно использовать Kivy

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться - в последние пару недель многие спрашивают про питон под андроид. Не знаете откуда такой наплыв?